# An error has occured: [object Object] error. ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The cause of the error in my code([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Gz39C/1/)) and how to fix?

> An error has occured:
>  [object Object]
>  error

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Gz39C/1/)

Comment: Start by cutting out the essential parts of your code. You may find the problem yourself, and if you fail at least you will be able to write a meaningful question instead of pasting a link to your code. I'm starting to have a strong detestation for jsfiddle.

Comment: Code size is too large, be hurt if I put it in here

Comment: Improve your question and I will explain...

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
```

Problem is that `String` + `Object` results in the `Object` being converted into a `String`, the default result is what you see as `[Object object]`.

Possible solutions:

1. On custom objects define a `toString()` and return whatever you want to see in the output.
2. use `JSON.stringify(obj)` to convert it into something more useful, this will of course break in cases where circular references exist.

Comment: @George: It's written there, under "Possible solutions". You might also profit form reading the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).